# Campaign member status "sent"

Tags: campaign-member

Not sure why "Sent" status is a default. May make sense for an email campaign, but at this point i am just adding leads to a campaign. I test a lead to make sure no email is sent out, but i am still concerned. 
Is salesforce sending anything? i dont see any triggers. 
thanks
andres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing being sent when you add a lead to a campaign.
You can customize the available status values yourself on the campaign detail page > "Advanced Setup"